# Multiple file upload ExtJs 4 via ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, extjs4, request

I'm using ExtJs4 for upload several files. 
Server side - ASP MVC.

**My problem: Request from extJS can't catch in action method!**

Ext code:

```
{
                    xtype: 'form',           
                    itemId: 'importForm',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [       
                        {
                            xtype: 'filefield',
                            name: 'IncFile',
                            fieldLabel: 'Choose files',
                            labelWidth: 200,
                            msgTarget: 'side',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            anchor: '100%',
                            buttonText: 'Choose',
                            listeners: {
                                afterrender: function (field) {
                                    field.fileInputEl.set({
                                        multiple: 'multiple'
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Load',
                            handler: function () {
                                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                                if (form.isValid()) {
                                    form.submit({
                                        url: 'Loader/Test',
                                        waitMsg: 'Loading...',
                                        success: function (fp, o) {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success','some message....');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]          
                }
```

Action in MVC controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
           //some code
        }
```

So, if I upload only one file - it's ok. I can get it from the Request.Files.
But, that is not working for multiple files! 
The request fails with '404 not found'.

**Here the request Payload:**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRkYIPo3BvQMnKfIJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="IncFile"; filename="file1.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


------WebKitFormBoundaryRkYIPo3BvQMnKfIJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="IncFile"; filename="file2.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


------WebKitFormBoundaryRkYIPo3BvQMnKfIJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="IncFile"; filename="file3.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


------WebKitFormBoundaryRkYIPo3BvQMnKfIJ--
```

Comment: you can better prefer this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 0):

So... The reason in web.config. My files are rather big.

This solved my problem.

```
  <system.webServer>
      .............
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```